# Sending emails with Mailgun occasionally hangs and doesn't send email

Tags: php, html, email, mailgun

So ive just implmented mailgun into a website for sending contact form info. 
This works some of the time, but mostly the page hangs when i press send with the message "waiting for *url*..." in the bottom left of chrome.

There is no ssl on the server hence the strange mailgun constructor.

This is my php which is placed just inside the body of my website.

```
<?php

        require 'mailgun-php/vendor/autoload.php';
        use Mailgun\Mailgun;

        if(isset($_POST['register'])){
            $message = "Contact Form.\n\n".
                "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n".
                "Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n".
                "Message: ".$_POST['message']."\n";

            $mg = new Mailgun(*my key*, "api.mailgun.net", "v2", false);
            $domain = *my domain*;

            $mg->sendMessage($domain, array(
                'from'=>'Contact Form <build@<url>>',
                'to'=> *email*,
                'subject' => ' Contact Form',
                'text' => $message
                )
            );
            header('Location: ?sent=1');
        }

    ?>
```

This is the form code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">

    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u$(mobile)"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
        <div class="6u$ 12u$(mobile)"><input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
        <div class="12u$">
            <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="12u$">
            <button class="button" type="submit" name="register"> Send Message </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I'm not getting any errors when the email is not sent. The page will eventually reload after the submit button is pressed but the header redirect is not being applied (which im assuming is because the email was not sent successfully).

The php error logs do not show anything going wrong either.

Thanks

Comment: This may be a bad day to test: http://status.mailgun.com/incidents/9nj4mzscl69g  The service should be back up and running(-ish) now.

Comment: @aynber would you say that this might be the reason for the hangs? it seems more like an issue with my site as the emaisl are never sent rather than a delay with them being sent.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular API, so I couldn't say fully. If it just submits to Mailgun, then no. If it submits and waits for a Delivered response, then possibly.

Comment: as far as im aware it does not wait for a delivered response as that can actually take a while after the api accepts the mail. maybe its just that api was not responding because of their fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's a (very) late answer, but I've just met the same problem. And I discovered, that Mailgun has whitelist of IP addresses, so in case you haven't added there your public IP address, the connection to Mailgun's API will never be established.
At the moment of writing this answer, the whitelist is present under this link: https://app.mailgun.com/app/account/security/api_keys

Comment: However it reads “Until a whitelist exists, all IPs are allowed access by default”.