# Mailgun messages().send having no apparent effect

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I am trying to send an email from my Node.js server using Mailgun.

I am using a free account, and I have added the destination email to my authorised reciever list and verified it.
I checked that the sending domain is active, and that Mailgun was installed and added as a dependency.

This is the relevant code:

```
const api_key = 'XXXXXXXX';
const domain = 'sandboxXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org/messages';

const mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
const mg = mailgun({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

const data = {
    from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
    to: 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
};

console.log('start');
mg.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log('sending email');
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(body);
});
console.log('end');
```

I also tried:

```
const domain = 'sandboxXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org';
```

I expected 'sending email' to be logged to the console, along with some message to indicate that the email has been queued or sent.
The actual output when I run 'firebase serve' is:

```
>  start
>  end
```

Everything else is working as expected. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have added your IP address to Mailgun's whitelist. 
I was having similar problem, take look at my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58381656/3079726

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the destination email address to an [authorized recipient](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients) so that he can accept the emails.

**If you configured already the email address to be an authorized recipient** and still cannot find the tests emails you've sent, then check the spam/junk section (I had them in spam in my gmail account).

Answer (score -1):

just add console log in send function and check what you are getting :

in your code :

replace `const mg = mailgun({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});`

with

```
const mg = new mailgun({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
```

full code :

```
var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

//Your api key, from Mailgun’s Control Panel
var api_key = 'MAILGUN-API-KEY';

//Your domain, from the Mailgun Control Panel
var domain = 'YOUR-DOMAIN.com';


var mailgun = new Mailgun({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
const data = {
    from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
    to: 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (err, body) {

    if (err) {  
        console.log("got an error: ", err);
    }

    else {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

Comment: I might be interpreting your answer wrong, but I believe this is already included in the initial question. I get no output to the console when I run your code.

Comment: Adding the 'new' keyword hasn't changed anything, same issue persists.